# Django SQL query duplicated n times

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a book model and a rating model,

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = AutoSlugField(unique=True, populate_from='title')
    description = models.TextField()
    # more fields

class Rating(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('library.Book')
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
```

the Query,

```
books = {'books': Book.objects.filter(pk__in=Rating.objects.all().order_by('-score'
              ).values_list('book__id', flat=True))[:10] }
```

template,

```
{% for i in books %}
   {{ i.title }}, {{ i.rating_set.all.first.score }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

renders the model to the template, but the django debug toolbar shows as Duplicated n times where n is the number of objects in the list. when I use queryset caching, its normal.

[image]

whats going on behind, how can I fix this?

thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Didn't test but you should definitely prefetch `rating_set` to not make additional database hit for each book to find their highest score:

```
rated_books = Rating.objects.all().order_by('-score').values_list('book', flat=True)
books = Book.objects.prefetch_related('rating_set').filter(pk__in=rated_books)[:10]
```

In the template, I also suspect `.first` and `.all` as they may cause an additional db hit. Besides, you don't need to call `.first` because we already know these *rated books* have at least one rating object.

```
{% for book in books %}
  {{ book.title }}, {{ book.rating_set.all.0.score }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

**Update: You need to use `rating_set.all.0` instead of `rating_set.0` to selec first rate**

Answer (score 4):

Read about [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

```
Book.objects.filter(pk__in=Rating.objects.all().order_by('-score').values_list('book__id', flat=True)).preferch_related('rating_set')[:10]
```

In template You want to access to book rating `{{ i.rating_set.all.0.score }}`. Without `select_related`/`prefetch_related` Django in each row make new query. With `prefetch_related` Django made 1 query and fetch all ratings.

In Your case the problem may be in `.first.`.

Comment: nothing changes, its something that occured when the template at the part `{{ i.rating_set.all.first.score }} `

Comment: changed `first` to `0` and now it is okay