# Django SQL query duplicated

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a **models.py** file containing this:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    time_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    #rest of code ...

class Question(Entry):

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_question', args=[self.id])

class Answer(Entry):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

By using Django-debug-toolbar I found out that I am duplicating many SQL queries.

What I am trying to do is get the last 5 questions asked, and display them in my home page, along with some more data containing Answers to those questions, the user who provided the answer, avatar of that user and etc and etc...

I am currently doing that with this views.py and home.html template:

**views.py**:

```
@login_required(login_url="accounts/login/")
def home_page(request):
    last_five = Question.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]
    last_five_in_ascending_order = list(reversed(last_five))
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'question_list': last_five_in_ascending_order,
    })
```

**home.html**:

```
{% for question in question_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'view_question' question.id %}">{{ question.text }}</a>
    {% if question.answer_set.all %}
        {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
            <img src="/media/{{ answer.created_by.userprofile.avatar }}" alt="">
            <a href="{% url 'profile' answer.created_by.id %}">
                {% firstof answer.created_by.get_full_name answer.created_by.username %}
            </a>
            {{ answer.time_passed }}
            {{ answer.text | safe }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I decrease my sql queries to the database?
And should I really be worried about these things? Do they make a difference for a website with little user activity?

Comment: So, what is your question??

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33587557/3901060. Use the select_related (or prefetch_related) QuerySet methods to join the questions and their answers in a single query.

Comment: @FazilZaid I forgot to ask my question :)) I have added it now.

Comment: @FamousJameous Yea I took a look at that but that doesn't cover the second part of my question. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is table inheritance rather than a simple many to one relationship and that makes like really complicated. I don't really see why a simple setup like this needs table inheritance here. Modifying your models like this works just as well

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    time_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    #rest of code ...

class Question(models.Model):
    entry = models.OneToOneField(Question)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_question', args=[self.id])

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    entry = models.OneToOneField(Question)
```

To solve your issue of many queries being executed. We now resort to [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)

```
Question.objects.select_related('entry)
Answer.objects.select_related('entry', 'question')
```

The debug toolbar will now show that repetitive queries have been eliminated.

> should I really be worried about these things? Do they make a
>   difference for a website with little user activity?

No all those queries are attempts to fetch related objects by their primary key. In any database, a lookup on a single item with a primary key is O(log (N)). But the base of the logarithm is usually a so you need not be concerned.

If you fetched them all at once it would be of course be faster since you are now having a single O(log (N)) operation with larger constants. But whether the difference is noticeable on a small site is debatable.

Comment: If I do it this way doesn't it add all of the texts to one table?
that would mean for every request it has to do a table join, wouldn't it?

I think my way is just creating 2 tables instead of 3 and no joining is required when I want a question or an answer.

Am I wrong? If I am, could you enlighten me with your knowledge please?

Comment: The way you are doing it now also adds all the texts to one table :-)

Comment: Joining __is__ what sql is all about. If you are scared of joins stay away from sql. The whole point of sql is that you spread data across tables and __join__ them. You are trying to do the opposite